# Oracle DELETE statement with subquery factoring

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ora-00928, subquery-factoring

Trying to do this (works in SQL Server):

```
WITH X AS (), Y AS (), Z AS ()
DELETE FROM TBL
WHERE TBL.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Z);
```

This works in Oracle:

```
WITH X AS (), Y AS (), Z AS ()
SELECT * FROM TBL
WHERE TBL.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Z);
```

But the DELETE does not: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

My subqueries are rather large, is there a different syntax to get this to work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot use Subquery Factoring/CTE with anything but the SELECT statement. [From the documentation:](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_10002.htm#i2077142)

> You can specify this clause in any
>   top-level SELECT statement and in most
>   types of subqueries.

You could do this:

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE tbl.id IN
(WITH X AS (), Y AS (), Z AS ()
SELECT id FROM TBL
 WHERE TBL.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Z));
```

Answer (score 9):

I got this to work (which I'm sure doesn't work in SQL Server):

```
DELETE FROM TBL
WHERE TBL.ID IN (
    WITH X AS (), Y AS (), Z AS ()
    SELECT ID FROM Z
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, at a minimum, you need to have all of the aliased queries appear in the FROM statement somehow. I don't know if there are more issues, but that is a must (and I believe that 00928 is the error that happens when you don't).

Comment: Yeah, I noticed Oracle won't let you leave an unused subquery hanging around like SQL Server will.